# Clean install of TeXworks on Win10, "pdfLaTeX not properly configured"

Tags: texworks

This seems like a relatively common problem, but all of the answers I have seen online boiled down to the user having done something tricky with their PATH environment, which I have not modified.

I just reinstalled TeXworks 0.6.5, chose all the default settings, and when I attempt to compile any document I get the following error message:

[image]

("pdfLaTeX not properly configured")

What can I try here?

Here are my typesetting settings:

[image]

As you can see, I have a few other programs that are trying to interface with TeXworks, although I never configured them to do so; could they be causing the issue?

Comment: Do you have actually a tex system?  Does it work if compile from a terminal?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I had installed *only* TeXworks when what I meant to install was the whole MikTeX distribution. Like many casual users, I never interact with anything other than TeXworks, so after a system restore, that was the name I remembered and the only thing I installed.

[Downloading MikTeX from here](https://miktex.org/download) and installing it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add the path for 'pdflatex.exe' in Edit, prefreferences, Path settings.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please add an screenshot?